# Can I import an iOS or OS X test target (dylib?) into my code using the command line?

Tags: xcode, testing, dylib

I'd like to build a tool that examines iOS or OS X test suites. Accordingly, I'd like a way to programmatically access the test objects.

My understanding that test targets in Xcode projects create dylibs. If so, how can I create, link, and import one such that I can access the classes within my own code?

Looking at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-somehash/Build/Products/<release-platform>/MyAppTests.xctest`, I see a binary file called `<testtarget>`. `file MyAppTests` gives:

```
MyAppTests: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

Using Swift (`xcrun swiftc`) or Objective-C (`xcodebuild`?), how can I import this file into my code, assuming that I understand correctly that this is a dylib?